# "No matching function" error with call to function template

Tags: c++, templates, glm-math

I want to use the GLM matrix header-only library to create a transformation matrix for my C++ graphics project. To test this out, I wrote the following simple code:

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>

int main()
{
    glm::mat4 projection_matrix = glm::perspective(45, 1.5, 0.1, 100);
    return 0;
}
```

However, I receive the following compilation error:

```
/home/Karnivaurus/Projects/GLMTest/src/main.cpp:6: error: no matching function for call to 'perspective(int, double, double, int)'
     glm::mat4 projection_matrix = glm::perspective(45, 1.5, 0.1, 100);
                                                                     ^
                                                                     ^
```

Followed by:

```
candidate is:
/usr/local/include/glm/gtc/matrix_transform.inl:218: template<class T> glm::detail::tmat4x4<T, (glm::precision)0u> glm::perspective(const T&, const T&, const T&, const T&)
  GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER detail::tmat4x4<T, defaultp> perspective
                                                  ^
```

Looking at the implementation of this function in the provided source code, I can see:

```
template <typename T>
    GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER detail::tmat4x4<T, defaultp> perspective
    (
        T const & fovy,
        T const & aspect,
        T const & zNear,
        T const & zFar
    )
    {
    //
    // The implementation ..........
    // .....
    // .....
    //
    }
```

I'm not particularly familiar with templates in C++. Can anybody explain this error to me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your example to:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const T&, const T& )
{ }

int main(){
    foo(45, 1.0); // error: no matching function for call to foo(int, double)
}
```

That is because when template deduction happens, it deduces `T` as `int` for the first argument and `double` for the second, but there is only one `T` so it has to be consistent! No conversions will happen for template deduction (it doesn't matter here that `int` and `double` are convertible to each other), so once we get inconsistent types, deduction fails - and since there is only one `foo`, there's no other overload to fall back on.

The solutions are either to ensure that the types are the same:

```
foo(45.0, 1.0); // calls foo<double>
foo(45, 1);     // calls foo<int>
```

Or to explicitly specify what `T` is:

```
foo<double>(45, 1.0);  // calls foo<double>, explicitly
```

In the latter case, no deduction occurs since we specified `T`, and this is equivalent to having called:

```
void foo(const double&, const double& );
```

so the first argument is just converted to `double`.

Comment: *How are you so fast ??*

Comment: @Quentin Typing class I took in elementary school was definitely the most valuable class of my life to date :)

Comment: I have no trouble believing you. Wow.

Answer (score 2):

As the function is declared, all of its parameters must be deduced to be of the same type `T`. In you call, you provide two `int`s and two `double`s. They are not identical, so the instanciation fails.

Change your call to :

```
glm::mat4 projection_matrix = glm::perspective(45.0, 1.5, 0.1, 100.0);
```

You can also specify the type explicitly to enable conversions :

```
glm::mat4 projection_matrix = glm::perspective<double>(45, 1.5, 0.1, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

The function template is defined with a single template parameter for all of its arguments. You're passing different types for the arguments, `int` for the first and last, and `double` for the middle arguments.

The fix would be to consistently use `double`s for all of the arguments:

```
glm::mat4 projection_matrix = glm::perspective(45.0, 1.5, 0.1, 100.0);
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. In this case, I actually needed to force them all to be floats because I think that glm::mat4 requires float data. So my solution was: `glm::mat4 projection_matrix = glm::perspective(45.0f, 1.5f, 0.1f, 100.0f);`